# map a sql like query to filter dictionaries list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionaries list and I want to apply a 'SQL like' filter query on it.

The user provides the string which can be something like this:

"type1==Hello && type2=~World" - AND operator

"type1==Hello || type2=~World" - OR operator

I managed to filter one argument for example "type1==Hello", without the && / ||.

Basically, I'm struggling to map the 'SQL like' format to a genuine filter on the dictionaries list using && || (and/or operators).

If someone can help me out, it will be great

```
def filter_host(hosts, filter_str, categories):
    def not_contains(a, b):
        return b not in a

    def and_(a, b):
        return a and b

    def or_(a, b):
        return a or b

    ops = {
        "==": operator.eq,
        "<": operator.lt,
        ">": operator.gt,
        "!=": operator.ne,
        '=~': operator.contains,
        '!~': not_contains,
        '&&': and_,
        '||': or_
    }

    try:
        key, op, value = re.match(r'(\w+)\s*(>|<|(?<!=)~=(?!=)|(?<!=)==(?!=)|(?<!=)>(?!=)|(?<!=)!~(?!=)|(?<!=)!=(?!=))\s*(\w*.*|\d*.*)',
                                  filter_str).groups()
        if key in categories:
            if _keys_mapping.get(key).get('type') == 'float':
                value = float(value)
            elif _keys_mapping.get(key).get('type') == 'int':
                value = int(value)
            operator_func = ops[op]
            filtered_hosts = list(filter(lambda host: operator_func(host.get(_keys_mapping[key]['name']), value), hosts))
            if filtered_hosts:
                return filtered_hosts
            else:
                raise Exception('No matching values')
        else:
            raise Exception('Key not exist. Allowed keys for this query are: ' + ', '.join(categories))
    except ValueError:
        handle_exceptions('Filter option not implanted')
    except AttributeError:
        handle_exceptions('Filter option not implanted')
```